# iPhone Audio send with Email path problem with device

Tags: iphone

```
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:strpath];
```

In simulator it works perfect but on device it got 0 bytes always.

I got device path like

```
`:/var/mobile/Applications/8DE11A6E-5D46-40BE-888D-E4336A1919DB/Documents/325078221276.caf`
```

and simulatore path

```
`:/Users/raincreatives/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/F00F4B1C-D454-4140-B189-7E7A0EBAA7BC/Documents/325078221276.caf`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file name simulator is not case sensitive where device is case sensitive. You might have problem with your file name